# flutter firebase database and ListView builder issue

Tags: firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, builder

I suppose to show each item of my shopList in ListView, but I can't find out the reason why it keep showing the same record. Please help to solve this issue.

Here with the code, get data from firebase database.

```
 databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic> getMap = snapshot.value;
    getMap.forEach((k, v) {

      Map<dynamic, dynamic> f = v;
      shop.key = k;
  shop.shopName = f["ShopName"];
  shop.tel = f["ShopTel"];
  shop.address = f["ShopAddress"];
  shop.thumbnail = f["Thumbnail"];
  debugPrint(k);

  shopList.add(shop);
  debugPrint(shopList[shopList.length-1].shopName);


});
  });
```

DebugPrint result:

- flutter: -LLySYDHHHx9WtCvKPrO
- flutter: shop1111
- flutter: -LLyXwR0nnAcx6_H4cYy
- flutter: shop2222

Here with the database:
[image]

Here with the code for ListView:

```
child: Flexible(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: shopList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return new Card(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        //elevation: 2.0,
                        child: new ListTile(

                          title: new Text("Name: ${shopList[index].key}"),

                        ),
                      );


                    }),
            ),
```

the result of simulator:

[image]

Comment: Why not use Firebase Animated List? Do you have an object called shop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

That's what I would do

**Shop.dart**

```
class Shop {
  String key;
  String name;
  String address;
  String phone;
  String thumbnail;

  Shop(this.name,this.address,this.phone,this.thumbnail);

  Shop.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        name = snapshot.value["name"],
        address= snapshot.value["address"],
        phone= snapshot.value["phone"],
        thumbnail= snapshot.value["thumbnail"];


  toJson() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "address": address,
      "phone": phone,
      "thumbnail": thumbnail,
    };
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
List<Shop> itemsShop = List();
Shop itemShop;
DatabaseReference itemRefShop;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  itemShop = Shop("", "", "", "");
  final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  itemRefShop = database.reference().child('Shop');
  itemRefShop.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAddedShop);
  itemRefShop.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChangedShop);
}

_onEntryAddedShop(Event event) {
  setState(() {
    itemsShop.add(Shop.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
  });
}

_onEntryChangedShop(Event event) {
  var old = itemsShop.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.key == event.snapshot.key;
  });
  setState(() {
      itemsShop[Shop.indexOf(old)] = Shop.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
  });
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             new Flexible(
              child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                     query: itemRefShop,
                     itemBuilder:(_, DataSnapshot snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index){
                       return new ListTile(
                         title: new Text(snapshot.value['name']),
                         subtitle: new Text(itemsShop[index].address),
                       );
                     }
               ),
          ]
        ),
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, May I know how and when  to terminate the firebase listener?

Comment: The _onEntryChangedShop events tell you the event that has changed, and the _onEntryAddedShop the event that they are added. You can use print(event.snapshot.value); inside each listening

Comment: for swift and kotlin, we have to stop the listener.  Shall we stop the listener somewhere?

Comment: You mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983923/how-to-reset-firebase-listeners-in-flutter 

You can read more here:
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html