# Flutter Firebase stops listening after push and pop operation

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I'm saving Firebase data in a list using on child Added listener and on child changed listener, it works good, but when i perform push operation and use pop to back to the screen the listeners stops listening.
Is there any solutions to fix this.

I used this code from Stackoverflow : [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249318/10916346)

Comment: Please show your push and pop code. Also, do you have code anywhere that cancels the listeners?

Comment: Use StreamSubscription to cancel listener

**My Push code**

`Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SweetsDetail(sweets)))`

**My Pop code**
`Navigator.of(context).pop(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this silly post, i'm new to flutter, I fixed this by using Future method in listeners.

@GrahamD you can find my code here.

My code:

```
var childAddedListener;
var childChangedListener;

@override
```

void initState(){

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);

reference = database.reference().child('Sweets');
childAddedListener = reference.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAddedShop);
childChangedListener = reference.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChangedShop);

super.initState();
```

}

**On Child Added Listener**

```
Future _onEntryAddedShop(Event event) {
setState(() {
  itemsShop.add(Sweets.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
});
```

}

**On Child Changed Listener**

```
Future _onEntryChangedShop(Event event) {
print('Child Changed');
var old = itemsShop.singleWhere((entry) {
  return entry.id == event.snapshot.key;
});
setState(() {
  itemsShop[itemsShop.indexOf(old)] = Sweets.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
});
getItemIds();
```

}

**Cancel them in dispose**

```
@override
dispose() {
  childAddedListener.cancel();
  childChangedListener.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted it out. 